# ToolStripControlHost stays always at top (C# window forms)

Tags: c#, toolstripdropdown, toolstripcontrolhost

I built a form, in this form i built a ToolStripControlHost:

```
ToolStripDropDown popup = new ToolStripDropDown();
popup.AutoClose = false;
popup.Margin = Padding.Empty;
popup.Padding = Padding.Empty;
ToolStripControlHost host = new ToolStripControlHost(control);
host.Margin = Padding.Empty;
host.Padding = Padding.Empty;
popup.Items.Add(host); 
popup.Show(0,0);
```

My problem is that the control stays as the top window when I move to other windows. I want it to belong to the form (meaning when i minimize the form, the control will be also minimized and ect..).
Thanks for helping.

Comment: You need to add popup to a ToolStrip.

Comment: can you explain more about it?